# Не получается добавить тур в избранное

Tags: javascript

Чистый JS. Все туры хранятся на сервере, данные уже получены, всё работает,
кроме "добавить в избранное"
и показать "избранные туры"

```
//отобразить все туры по клику
let buttonAllTours = document.getElementById("allToursBtn")

buttonAllTours.addEventListener("click", () => {
     renderTours(tours)
} )

let favoriteTours = [] //массив с любимыми турами

tours.forEach((tour) => {
    
let buttonAddToFavorite = document.getElementById(`button-addFavorite-${tour.id}`) //нахожу кнопку каждого тура
buttonAddToFavorite.addEventListener("click", () => {

    const tour = tours.find((findTour) => { //находим нужный тур
        return findTour.id === id //находим id тура
    })
    favoriteTours.push(tour) //добавляем тур в любимые
    
    let allFavoritesTours = document.getElementById("favoriteToursBtn")    //находим "показать избранные туры"
    allFavoritesTours.addEventListener("click", () => {
        renderTours(favoriteTours)
    })
})
})
```

Comment: `return findTour.id === id` тут же ты берешь переменную id, которой нет. Ты должен сравнить с tour.id: `return findTour.id === tour.id`

Comment: на сервере есть данные, в которых хранится id. А заранее я получаю с помощью fetch данные с сервера

Comment: добавил ответ, посмотри может так

Answer (score 0):

```js
const clearTours = () => {
  // Функция очищает туры 
  const toursComponent = document.getElementById("toursList");
  toursComponent.textContent = "";
};

const renderTours = (tours) => {
  // Функция рендиринга туров 

  clearTours(); // Очищаем туры, чтобы не дублировались

  const toursComponent = document.getElementById("toursList");

  for (let tour of tours) {
    const tourComponent = document.createElement("div");
    tourComponent.innerHTML = tour.text;
    tourComponent.id = `button-addFavorite-${tour.id}`;
    tourComponent.addEventListener("click", () => {
      favoriteTours.push(tour);
    });

    toursComponent.appendChild(tourComponent);
  }
};

const tours = [{
    id: 0,
    text: "Тур 1"
  },
  {
    id: 1,
    text: "Тур 2"
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    text: "Тур 3"
  },
];

let favoriteTours = []; //массив с любимыми турами

let buttonAllTours = document.getElementById("allToursBtn");

buttonAllTours.addEventListener("click", () => {
  favoriteTours = [];
  renderTours(tours);
});

let allFavoritesTours = document.getElementById("favoriteToursBtn"); //находим "показать избранные туры"
allFavoritesTours.addEventListener("click", () => {
  renderTours(favoriteTours);
});
```

```html
<button id="allToursBtn">allToursBtn</button>
<button id="favoriteToursBtn">favoriteToursBtn</button>
<div id="toursList"></div>
```

Comment: Уже стало лучше, но по-прежнему не работает))

Comment: Поправил, сейчас должно работать

Comment: В вашем варианте работает, но в моем нет)))